# NetworkManager tray (nm-applet) is gone after upgrade to 14.04 Trusty

Tags: 14.04, xubuntu, lubuntu, network-manager

I upgraded from 13.10 to 14.04 and now the nm-applet no longer shows in the system tray. I already tried purging and reinstalling the network-manager-gnome package but that didn't help. When I run nm-applet manually in the terminal I get the following output:

```
** (nm-applet:7419): WARNING **: Couldn't connect to accessibility bus: Failed to connect to socket /tmp/dbus-gBrnqcTAVj: Connection refused
```

I tried multiple system trays: i3bar (my default), trayer and the xfce4-panel. Other tray apps work in all three of them (like dropbox). The network manager itself works, as it connects to known networks and outputs notifications.
Does someone know how to fix this?

Comment: I have the same issue, but the page linked in Guest's answer doesn't help. I use xfce4 in ubuntu 14.04 and did see the network manager applet icon in the notification area after first upgrading to 14.04, but a couple of days later it disappeared. I'm guessing it must be an update I applied after upgrading to 14.04. ```nm-applet``` and ```NetworkManager``` are both running, and if I edit ```/usr/share/applications/gnome-network-panel.desktop``` to say ```OnlyShowIn=GNOME;XFCE;``` then run ```gnome-control-center network``` I can connect to wireless networks, and the ```nm-applet``` bubbles pop

Answer (score 21):

You could use the indicator plugin instead, but you may see frequent crashes. The  crash is caused by the Applications Menus indicator. Add the indicator plugin and, before it crashes, right click on it, choose 'properties' and tick the 'hidden' checkbox next to the 'Application Menus (Global Menu)'  indicator. Then restart the panel with 'xfce4-panel -r'

Instead, I fixed nm-applet by changing the 'Exec' line in /etc/xdg/autostart/nm-applet.desktop to 'dbus-launch nm-applet'

Comment: I agree, changing nm-applet.desktop as in your second paragraph is what's worked for me, on multiple machines that I've been upgrading from 13.10 to 14.04, with xfce.  Needs a reboot after first editing that file, and there's a few seconds delay each time after logging in before the indicator appears on the bar, but it works.

Comment: Changing nm-applet.desktop worked for me as well. One thing to add, I got tripped up for a while because I unknowingly had a `~/.config/autostart/nm-applet.desktop` file which was overriding this. I removed that and everything worked fine.

Comment: Using `dbus-launch nm-applet` displayed me the network manager directly in the notification area instead of using the Unity indicator plugin. Thank you for sharing this, I had a bug with nm-applet on Xubuntu, I have the panel at the bottom of the screen and sometimes when I click on nm-applet, the indicator menu is too short and I have to scroll to see all WiFi networks. Probably this bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-panel/+bug/965953 A better solution is to completely remove xfce4-indicator-plugin and indicator-application so applications can use directly notification area.

Answer (score 18):

It turns out that to see the nm-applet icon, you have to install package "xfce4-indicator-plugin" and add "Indicator Panel" to the panel.

That adds a whole bunch of icons that you probably don't want, and that ignore your theme choice.  But at least you'll have the nm-applet icon again.  For a while.  The indicator-panel dies every few seconds for me, and when it does stay running long enough for me to try configuring it, the configuration panel doesn't work either.

Your mileage may vary - try the "Indicator Panel" and see if it works for you.

Comment: yes! and this also shows skype status again :-)

Comment: The indicator panel is way too buggy. Whenever I switch desktop the indicator crashes...

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, but i just kill 'indicator-application-service' and icons network, bluetooth and skype appear again. I use xfce on amd64.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution to this problem here: http://linuxg.net/how-to-fixrestore-the-missing-network-manager-from-the-unity-top-panel-on-ubuntu-13-04-raring-ringtail-and-ubuntu-12-10-quantal-quetzal/

Quoting their site: The fix for this issue is simple, first stop the network-manager service, like this:

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/network-manager stop
```

Delete the /var/lib/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.state file:

```
$ sudo rm /var/lib/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.state
```

Turn back on the network-manager service:

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/network-manager start
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue and came across this solution: 
http://www.webupd8.org/2014/04/fix-lubuntu-1404-network-manager.html

Hope this helps!

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

I blatantly stole the answer from one of the comments to http://www.webupd8.org/2014/04/fix-lubuntu-1404-network-manager.html as Adz linked to and Eric Carvalho suggested be included in an actual answer. So, now we have the answer here in AskUbuntu. This is what I did.

> Dimitrios Charalampidis
>   
> This fix does not work for everybody... if that's the case for you, too.. then try this: go to menu >Preferences > Default applications for LXSession, select the autostart tab and scroll to find Network. Uncheck it and recheck it, then go to your home folder and press ctrl+h to show hidden files and folders, go to .config/autostart, there you will find a Network.desktop file right click on it and select Leafpad, it is likely that under NotShowIn section it includes LXDE just delete it, save the file and exit, then log out and login again this will fix the issue.

For those that came looking for the actual answer on that website, here it is.

> Lubuntu 14.04: fix 1
>
> To fix the Network Manager not showing up on the panel issue, from the Lubuntu menu select Preferences > Default applications for LXSession, then click on the Autostart tab and under "Manual autostarted applications" type "nm-applet", then click the "+ Add" button on the left:
>
> Now log out, log back in and you should see the Network Manager icon on the panel:
>
> fix somewhat via lffl.org
>
> Lubuntu 14.04 / Xubuntu 14.04: fix 2
>
> If the above solution didn't work for you in Lubuntu 14.04 or if you're using Xubuntu 14.04 and you're having this issue, here's another solution. Basically, the solution below is for those who must run "nm-applet" as root to get it to show up in the pane - we'll be using dbus-launch to launch nm-applet at startup.
>
> To get the Network Manager applet to work properly in either Lubuntu 14.04 or Xubuntu 14.04, run the following command:
>   sudo sed -i 's/Exec=nm-applet/Exec=dbus-launch nm-applet/' /etc/xdg/autostart/nm-applet.desktop
>   The command above replaces "nm-applet" with "dbus-launch nm-applet" in the nm-applet autostart desktop file.

**UPDATED**
Ok, I also followed the advice from here:
http://www.bauer-power.net/2014/05/permanent-fix-for-missing-network.html

> What you need to do is edit /etc/xdg/autostart/nm-applet.desktop with your favorite text editor. I like nano, so I ran the following from the terminal:
>   sudo nano /etc/xdg/autostart/nm-applet.desktop
>   Go down to the Exec line and change the entry from nm-applet to dbus-launch nm-applet. Save the file and reboot!