# System tray icons disappeared after upgrading Ubuntu

Tags: unity, indicator

I have many applications with tray icons like davmail, hardware monitor. I miss this feature on Ubuntu 14.04. Does anyone have a solution?

There are some tools like Skype indicator, but I need a general solution for this problem so that I can add application icons to the system tray.

Comment: Have you tried [this solution](http://askubuntu.com/questions/74229/how-to-access-skype-in-unity/74951#74951) from [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/74229/how-to-access-skype-in-unity)?

Answer (score 159, accepted):

### You may need to do two things:

#### 1. Install the *sni-qt* libraries.

Install [*sni-qt* [image: Install banshee]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/sni-qt) (click on the link), or with `sudo apt-get install sni-qt sni-qt:i386` from the terminal, and then restart Skype. The tray/panel icon should now be back!

> The reason this step is required is because *sni-qt* is installed automatically by the Ubuntu repository Skype package, but NOT by the Skype deb you directly download. Once Skype 4.0 is in the Ubuntu repos, you can install from there and this will no longer be necessary.

#### 2. You *may* also need to whitelist the indicator

We don't know why, but for some systems this additional step is required before the indicator will show (thanks to [Bruno Pereira](https://askubuntu.com/users/25863/bruno-pereira)!)

**Steps**:

1. Install the package [`dconf-tools`[image: Install dconf-tools]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/dconf-tools) (click on the link), or from the terminal with `sudo apt-get install dconf-tools`
2. Open *dconf editor* from the Dash (or `dconf-editor` from terminal):

   [image]
3. On the left sidebar, use the triangles to navigate to  *desktop* > *unity* > 
   *panel*. On Ubuntu 12.10 you instead need to navigate to *com* > *canonical* > *unity* > *panel*. Double-click on the orange `[JavaEmbedded...]` part on the right, and add `,'skype'` to allow the Skype indicator to show, as below:

   [image]
4. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, close *dconf editor*, logout and login -- your indicator should now be back!

Comment: In Ubuntu 12.10 I found it at a different path within `dconf-editor`: *com > canonical > unity > panel*.

Comment: This works on gnome-classic too.

Comment: Works great, in case one has to install skype on 64bit OS, I followed these steps. 
`$ sudo apt-get install libxss1`
`$ cd /tmp`
`$ wget http://www.skype.com/go/getskype-linux-ubuntu-64/skype-ubuntu-precise_4.1.0.20-1_amd64.deb`
`$ sudo dpkg -i skype-ubuntu*.deb`

Comment: On Ubuntu 12.10 you do not have a `panel` item under unity. :( One Zero's answer works though.

Comment: As of 13.04, both _com > canonical > unity > panel_ and _desktop > unity > panel_ are not there. IMO the right solution is to install skype from repository as described [here](http://askubuntu.com/a/286601/44115)

Comment: While `sni-qt` package was installed, I still needed to whitelist the indicator for icon to appear in tray. Now it works - thanks a lot!

Comment: Can confirm this works great on 13.10, and I didn't need to whitelist it. Just installing that package and quitting then starting Skype again fixed it :)

Comment: Yes, no need to do any whitelisting in Ubuntu 13.10

Comment: In Ubuntu 14.04, I found I needed to change Skype with a capital letter to skype all lower-case before the icon was permitted. Skype with a capital had previously worked before I upgraded to 14.04 / Trusty.

Comment: Working for Mint also :)

Comment: Don't forget to log out/in (or restart unity) for this to take effect.

Comment: confirm this works also with kde 5.3 and plasma 5

Comment: in LTS 14.04 "sudo apt-get install sni-qt:i386"  on the terminal and restarting Skype did the trick

Comment: This is still the solution for Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Ubuntu 17 and I can't find particular entry with dconf-editor

Answer (score 67):

To have Skype Tray Icon displayed in Ubuntu, install `sni-qt` package:

```
sudo apt-get install sni-qt:i386
```

Comment: this actually made it work for me in 14.04 - and it is sni-qt:i386 not just sni-qt. (on my system (64 bit) skype is also installed as skype:i386). Perhaps it is the same problem for other apps.

Comment: upgraded ubuntu from 12.04 to 14.04 (dirty install), skype tray icons disappeared. this fixed it

Comment: More info on why this works: http://askubuntu.com/a/151118/48105. Oh, and don't forget to logoff/login (or restart unity) for this to take effect.

Comment: On 14.04.01 I only needed to kill and restart Skype after installing sni-qt:i386. Works great.

Comment: Still the solution for 16.04 (sad to know the problem persits).

Answer (score 19):

Enable Skype Icon on Unity Notification Panel on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

When you do a fresh install of Ubuntu 12.04 (Or any version with Unity for that matter), you install Skype and expect it to work as it used to. But if you close the main window - you soon notice that Skype icon is not being displayed in top panel.

To fix this you will need to run a few commands. So open up your terminal and run this:

```
gsettings get com.canonical.Unity.Panel systray-whitelist
```

You should get something like this:

```
['JavaEmbeddedFrame', 'Wine', 'Update-notifier']
```

Basically this means, that Skype is not whitelisted, thus is not allowed by default to display its tray icon. We need to fix this. Append 'Skype' to the list so that you have something like this:

```
['JavaEmbeddedFrame', 'Wine', 'Update-notifier', 'Skype']
```

Then wrap it with double quotes (”) and add gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Panel systray-whitelist in front of it. At this point you should have something like this:

```
gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Panel systray-whitelist "['JavaEmbeddedFrame', 'Wine', 'Update-notifier', 'Skype']"
```

Now just copy this to your Terminal and execute the command. Reboot afterwards. Now you should see the icon.

Source: [Enable Skype icon on Unity notification panel on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS - Tautvidas Sipavičius](http://www.tautvidas.com/blog/2012/05/enable-skype-icon-on-unity-panel-on-ubuntu-12-dot-04-lts/)

Comment: Thank you for providing the commands b/c when I open DConf editor I don't see a Panel option under Unity.  This worked well for me after I also installed sni-qt (not sure that was required).

Comment: After the first command: `No such schema 'com.canonical.Unity.Panel'`. Ubuntu 13.04 64-bit.

Comment: Same here: "No such schema" Ubuntu 13.04 64 bit

Comment: Here: Systray on Ubuntu 13.04 http://www.webupd8.org/2013/05/how-to-get-systray-whitelist-back-in.html

Answer (score 10):

This is because Ubuntu has turned off whitelisting since version 13.10.  Here are two options to fix:

either

```
sudo apt-get install libappindicator1
```

or

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:gurqn/systray-trusty
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

For more information:
[System Tray icons not showing](https://askubuntu.com/questions/447739/system-tray-icons-not-showing)
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2217458
https://launchpad.net/~gurqn/+archive/systray-trusty

Comment: it doesn't work in 14.04

Comment: libappindicator1 on its own didn't work for me (from a clean 14.04 AMD64 install), but it worked after also installing systray-trusty (including the manual gedit step) AND restarting.

Comment: for Utopic, you should use `ppa:gurqn:systray-utopic`, if it does matter

Comment: Vivid version also available `ppa:gurqn:systray-vivid`

Answer (score 9):

I was facing this problem too. Installing following package solved my problem.

```
sudo apt-get install sni-qt:i386
```

I am on Ubuntu 15.10, `sni-qt:i386` was required for the systray icon to show up.

Comment: This is the best solution for Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. The registry fix doesn't work. Restart Skype after installing sni-qt:i386

Answer (score 5):

maybe you need to whitelist skype to the notification area (i'm not sure if skype includes an appindicator)

The easy way to make it is installing dconf-tools

```
sudo apt-get install dconf-tools
```

or Using Software Center [image: Install via the software center]

Then press <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f2</kbd> and enter dconf-editor to see a program like this:

[image: dconf-editor]

Navigate to `desktop`-->`unity`-->`panel` and add the apps that you like to whitelist to the end of the list (in your case you must add 'Skype') separate by comas. You can instead write `all` to whitelist all apps to use the notification area.

You will need to log out and log in again yo apply the changes.

More info:  http://www.webupd8.org/2011/04/how-to-re-enable-notification-area.html

Comment: I don't see 'panel' under unity. Am I missing something? I'm on 14.04

Comment: Probably the path have changed for 14.04, can't say for sure because I'm not using Unity right now

Answer (score 4):

Here's what worked for me to get both the Skype and Franz indicator back under Ubuntu 16.10 64-bit Unity Desktop

1) I installed sni-qt:i386 as mentioned [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/456950/system-tray-icons-disappeared-after-installing-ubuntu-14-04/507151#507151) with  `sudo apt-get install sni-qt:i386`

2) I installed libappindicator as mentioned [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/362135/how-to-re-enable-tray-icons-for-applications-in-ubuntu/370654#370654) with `sudo apt-get install libappindicator1`

3) Finally I installed the .deb package found at http://ppa.launchpad.net/nilarimogard/webupd8/ubuntu/pool/main/p/pidgin-indicator/ via the software center. As mentioned [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/362135/how-to-re-enable-tray-icons-for-applications-in-ubuntu/419281#419281), this provided the final resolution.

Comment: Thank you so much for your efforts! Just a question: why do we need to install the Pidgin Indicator if we only need to fix Skype and Franz?

Comment: While I wouldn't doubt that the reason why could be found in the pidgin-indicator .deb package, all I know right now is it worked for me. Unfortunately I don't have the time to dig into it further at the moment.

Comment: My problem must be something else. Even after installing Pidgin Indicator, I still experience the problem...

Comment: That's odd, did you do all 3 steps?

Comment: Yes but never mind please. It's not that important if the problem only really affects me. I can live with it.

Comment: This worked pretty well for me. At the first run Skype froze for some reason but from the second it started to work.

Comment: I had to do only the first two steps and it worked : )

Comment: @PetarVasilev excellent. I'm glad it helped!

Answer (score 3):

**Reference**

Here I post you an [article](http://www.tautvidas.com/blog/2012/05/enable-skype-icon-on-unity-panel-on-ubuntu-12-dot-04-lts/) that explains how to include Skype in a Unity system tray whitelist.

I have Ubuntu 12.04, it worked for me!

**Details**

Basically, open a new terminal and execute this:

```
gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Panel systray-whitelist "['JavaEmbeddedFrame', 'Wine', 'Update-notifier', 'Skype']"
```

and then restart Skype.

Answer (score 2):

If your are using gnome shell, activate this extension call **Status Icon Fixer**

Fixes Dropbox, Skype, vlc and others into the status bar; not perfect, but ok.

https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/192/status-icon-fixer/

Comment: For Ubuntu 13.10 and newer, **Status Icon Fixer** reportedly does not work any more. I use the alternative **[Top Icons](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/495/topicons/)** extension for 13.10 and it works well.

Answer (score 2):

For me the path in dconf editor was:

```
com -> canonical -> indicator -> appmenu -> messages
```

And then click on **applications** and in value add *'skype'*.
I'm running Ubuntu 13.10 (64-bit).

Comment: Did not work for 14.04 Trusty.

Answer (score 2):

A solution that **works as of Dec 2015** in Ubuntu 14.04 is to install the following PPA:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:fixnix/indicator-systemtray-unity
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install indicator-systemtray-unity
```

This gives you an arrow in the taskbar that you may click to show your icons. You can also have the icons show in the bar itself and instructions for that can be found here: http://www.webupd8.org/2015/05/on-demand-system-tray-for-ubuntu.html

Why don't the other solutions work anymore? Updates to Unity keep breaking the other ppa solutions and it seems no one is committed to keeping them up to date.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the Skype->Options.

In the General Category check "Start Skype minimized in the System Tray".

Comment: nope that didn't change anything. But the option is (in german) rather labeled start minimized (says nothing about the system tray). So now I just have to click two times on the button in the Launcher

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Gnome-Flashback (formerly Fallback/Classic) with a tint2 panel. I tried all of these fixes and none of them worked for me. I even tried

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:timekiller/unity-systrayfix
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

No luck. Even tried killing tint2 and using the gnome-panel instead. Still no icons for many, but not all, of my apps.

I finally found a solution while looking for a way to get(specifically) the network manager to show in the systray [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/458800). Since I use Cairo-Dock as a launcher, I just changed all the launch commands for my apps that weren't showing up to `dbus-launch app-launch-command`. Where `app-launch-command` is the regular launch command for that app. Did the same for Startup applications and it works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

This solution works fine with Ubuntu 17.04

> Simply run the application with "env XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=Unity". For
>   example, to start Skype For Linux, you would use:
>
> ```
> env XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=Unity skypeforlinux
> ```
>
> To make the fix permanent, copy the application desktop file from
>   /usr/share/applications/ to ~/.local/share/applications/, then edit
>   the file and change the "Exec" line by adding "env
>   XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=Unity" (without the quotes) immediately after
>   "Exec=".

More details at http://www.webupd8.org/2017/04/fix-appindicator-not-working-for.html

Answer (score -2):

I had the same issue.  Here is what I did to correct it.

Open Terminal

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get install unity
sudo shutdown -r now
```

Comment: Every solution doesn't comes with reinstall, atleast not in ubuntu.