# Screencloud Tray Icon Disappeared, Already Installed libqt4-svg

Tags: unity, 14.04, indicator, system-tray

I was messing around with a lot of programs and files last night trying to get some things to work. Then, when I turned my computer on this morning, I noticed that my screencloud tray icon had disappeared. Screencloud still works, but instead of opening up a dialogue box after taking a screenshot like I set it to, it automatically uploads the picture and shows a little message from the top-left corner of the screen.

I looked at other similar questions and saw that the people were missing libqt4-svg, but I not only already had that installed but also reinstalled it to see if that would fix it, but it was to no avail.

The problem may have something to do with the messing around I was doing last night since when I first turned it on my background was messed up too, but I was able to fix that.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: ScreenCloud dev here. Do you have [sni-qt](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/sni-qt) installed?

Answer (score 0):

This question is related to this [one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/456950/system-tray-icons-disappeared-after-installing-ubuntu-14-04). It happen to me after an update the icons disappear.

You should do the following.

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:gurqn/systray-trusty
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

This is an article of [Ubuntu Forum](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2217458)